# What exactly is the uri parameter for in the Intent constructor?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, uri

I've tried searching the web and looking through Google's documentation, but I've struggled to find anything that explains what it's used for or any example that shows it passed into the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sets the data that you want the Intent to operate on.  It's the same as calling the default constructor `new Intent()` and then calling `setData(uri)`.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(i);
```

This starts the `ACTION_VIEW` Intent to view the google webpage.

Comment: I'm assuming then how it's used is entirely dependant on the activity being called on?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  For example, the intent to take a picture with the camera sets the data to be the Uri of the newly saved image on the device.

Comment: And would that be any different than doing the following? `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);`

Comment: My example was what the camera intent returns to the caller.  When you're actually calling the camera intent, you need to specify that extra.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is, is there a difference between the above statement, and simply plugging the uri into the constructor when creating the intent (i.e. `Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, imageUri);`)?

Comment: Yes, if you're specifically talking about the camera intent you do not set the Uri data when calling the camera, you have to specify the EXTRA_OUTPUT extra.